# Physical impact sensor for detecting mail dropped in letterbox

Tags: sensor, embedded

I would like to attach a sensor to the bottom of my letterbox so that when a parcel or a letter is dropped in it I would receive instant notification. Ideally the sensor would be able to be configured to certain impact threshold and to report the value.

What kind of sensor could I use for that purpose? What kind of device could it be connected to which would be able to trigger a network event (e.g. HTTP request)?

The letterbox is [this one](http://www.parcelprotector.co.nz/gallery/) (not my photo):

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better to use something to detect when there is a letter *in* the mailbox, so that it's not possible to miss it when it happens, so that you'll detect even small letters, and so you won't detect trucks driving past.

Comment: Something like a photocell? If the sensor goes dark, message delivered

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr multiple letters/parcels can be dropped. The sensor needs to react every time it happens.

Comment: @Greendrake: Then you may have to add a platform and loadcell (a weighing scales) in the bottom of your postbox. With that connected to a microcontroller you can detect changes in weight whether the item lands with high or slow velocity.

Comment: What about a sensor that is in kitchen scales? You will actually measure weight.

Comment: Alexander’s suggestion of the photocell is good - once there is one letter you know you have to go and get it - does not matter if there is one or many. A method of ignoring tax letters may be popular....

Comment: @Transistor 's answer seems to be the best

Comment: Why not a simple switch on the shutter?

Comment: @Maple I am a total noob in switches/shutters. Can you tell more please?

Comment: I was thinking if your mailbox has a lid or flapping shutter then you can add a switch to it. Whenever something placed inside the switch closes and lights up a LED. The whole thing is just a few parts and about an hour of work, including attaching switch to mailbox. The simpler the design the more reliable it is.

Comment: @Maple The mailbox indeed has a lid for parcels. But it also has a slit for letters, for placing which the lid does not need to be used. When the postie drops a letter in through the slit, the sensor needs to let me know.

Comment: That is why I mentioned shutter too. Basically a lightweight hinged panel covering the slit on the inside.

Comment: @Greendrake  Can you post a picture of your letterbox?

Comment: @NickAlexeev photo added